# How can I create an array of comma separated arrays using java

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc

I am trying to use the `google maps API` to list multiple locations in a web page using my `Java Spring MVC Web Application`. The locations are stored in my database. 
Now I am trying to return a list of locations in the following format:

```
['ABC', -33.890542, 151.274856],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302]
```

I need this format since the locations is called as follows in the script:

```
var locations = [
      ['ABC', -33.890542, 151.274856],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302]
    ];
```

What I am trying to do is to create this arrays using Java and then pass it to the UI. I am not sure how to create such an array structure using Java.

Comment: google: "java two dimensional array"

Comment: I'd recommend using a json library to let it generate that json string for you. I'm not sure whether spring already supplies one or whether there's a preference but the most commonly used would be Jackson or Gson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the array contains items of different data types. this creates a problem in statically typed languages like Java. the array will have to be defined `Object[]` which is problematic since the compiler will not be able to help you populate the array properly.

You should design the API between the server and client to use array of Json objects. something like

```
[
  {"Name": "Coogee Beach", "longitude":-33.923036, "latitude":151.259052},
  {"Name": "Cronulla Beach", "longitude":-34.028249, "latitude":151.157507},
  ...
]
```

this is best represented in Java by creating a class with properties that match the JSON object:

```
public class Place {
  public String name;
  public double longitude;
  public double latitude;
}
```

you should create an array (or `List`) of `PLace`s and you can use one of the many Jason libraries that map Java objects to-from Json objects.

Comment: I was also planning the same by creating a POJO and then returning the list . But how can I get that vale in the script as follows:  <script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
      ['<strong>Chipotle on Sheridan</strong><br>\r\
     6600 N Sheridan Rd<br> Chicago, IL 60626<br>', -33.890542, 151.274856],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302]
    ];

Comment: does it have to be like that? because it is just bad design

Comment: All I am trying to do is load a map with multiple markers where the data is from the database which has to be returned by a Spring MVC controller

Comment: you need to understand that server-client api and the google maps api are two different things with different requirements and functionalities. the JavaScript client can accept array of json objects and translate that into the data structure that google maps expects

Answer (score 1):

The design of returning lat/long in array doesn't look great, but here's the solution that should work.

```
Object[][] result = new Object[list.size()][3];
for (int i = 0; i < list.size; i++) {
    result[i][0] = list[i].locName;
    result[i][1] = list[i].latitude;
    result[i][2] = list[i].longitude;
}
return result;
```

Comment: what is `list`??

Comment: list is the list of locations returned from the database.